# MySQL query using AND & OR operators

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below loads all conversations, however, I wanted to only load the conversation between two people.

```
SELECT * FROM msg 
WHERE senderid = '{$sender}' 
OR recid = '{$recipient}' 
OR recid = '{$sender}' 
OR senderid = '{$recipient}' 
order by id asc
```

How would I use the AND & OR operators together? Would the following work?

```
SELECT * FROM msg 
WHERE senderid = '{$sender}' 
AND recid = '{$recipient}' 
OR recid = '{$sender}' 
AND senderid = '{$recipient}' 
order by id asc
```

Comment: Still, be careful with mixing AND and OR in boolean expressions. It is easy to make mistakes. Use parentheses to be safe.

Answer (score 4):

When using `AND` and `OR` together, use parentheses to group your logic and make sure the it does what you expect:

```
SELECT * FROM msg 
WHERE (senderid = '{$sender}' AND recid = '{$recipient}')
OR    (recid = '{$sender}' AND senderid = '{$recipient}')
order by id asc
```

Comment: I'd like to add for other people that it's always much better to have too many parentheses (brackets?) than too few!

Comment: @jslvtr Agreed! On an additional note, further clarification on used terminology can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket :)

Answer (score 0):

Please find below.

```
SELECT * FROM msg 
WHERE (senderid = '{$sender}' AND recid = '{$recipient}') 
OR (recid = '{$sender}' AND senderid = '{$recipient}') 
order by id asc
```